# calling a url that does not contain http in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4 for my front end.I have a URL that should be called by a button.But my URL does not contain http:// part.

here is my URL

file://192.0.0.70/Users/......./SupportDocs/Employee/EV201801093/EV201801093-Revenue%20Licence.pdf

below ways I have tried but not working

```html
window.location.href='';
this.router.navigateByUrl('');
```

Comment: It will not work. Because it is in your hard drive. It is not in the server system. Copy this PDF in you assets or images folder and then provide a relative path.

Comment: I don't think file extension works with an ip. You'll want to use http if this ip can truly serve the pdf.

Comment: if I copy the link and past it to my address bar of the browser its working.Is there any method to pass this url to the address bar?

Comment: Its is different than you address bar. Imagine if JavaScript or any website html can access local file system than what will happen? All your data will be theft. So it is now allowed from web browser. It puts the restriction.

Comment: yes I got it thank you very much